# Custom Admin Message from external source to multiple users

Tags: wp-admin, updates

I am administrator for several wordpress sites. Each site has an editor and I would like to find a way to be able to write a single message in an external centralised place, and have that message display in each client's Wordpress admin (e.g. an info notice), similar to the update nag.

At the moment, we use a plugin on each site to display static info, but this is not really ideal for sending a quick message to each client site.

I have looked at several plugins but nothing appears to offer the simple functionality that I need.  One message, typed centrally, then pulled in to each admin - probably via a plugin that calls for the message?

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: One approach: Set a message in separate server. Develope JSON api to provide message as per request. For the WP setup, develop a plugin to create nag message. For nag message pull it from your main server using JSON.

Comment: Yes, I had already developed the nag message and a plugin on the external server, but how to JSON to each individual dashboard, and in a secure way!

Comment: This may be the option? `wp_remote_get`. [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get)